Function runs slowly (12s) from PHP but quick (sub-second) in SSMS. What are some areas of investigation?
I have a SQL Server function that uses several WITH CTEs to pre-process some data prior to the output in FOR JSON PATH format.
The query runs sub-second in SSMS but is taking twelve seconds when called from our test PHP web application.
I am aware of 'parameter sniffing' for stored procedures, but I am unclear whether this is the same for functions, and if so how to fix the issue. In stored procedures, the use of local variables improves the parameter sniffing issues, but I am unaware of a similar fix for functions.
Where else are good starting points to investigate such an issue?
As requested below the PHP code is as follows:
include '../connections/iconnection.inc';
$inputJSON = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$decodedJSON = (json_decode($inputJSON, true));
$SQLStmt = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_JSON_QueryPricingForOrder_v5.0] (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
$SQLPrms=array();
(!empty($decodedJSON['siteid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['siteid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['contractorid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['contractorid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['containerid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['containerid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['wastetypeid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['wastetypeid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['containersizeid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['containersizeid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['productcategoryid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['productcategoryid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['producttypeid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['producttypeid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['productid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['productid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['serviceid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['serviceid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['wastesubtypeid']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['wastesubtypeid']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
(!empty($decodedJSON['wastesubtypeqty']) ? array_push($SQLPrms,$decodedJSON['wastesubtypeqty']) : array_push($SQLPrms,NULL));
$RS_Result01 = sqlsrv_query($conn01,$SQLStmt,$SQLPrms);
if ($RS_Result01 === false) {
    $_SESSION['error-url'] = basename(__FILE__);
    $_SESSION['error-line'] = __LINE__;
    $_SESSION['error-sqlmsg'] = sqlsrv_errors();
    $_SESSION['error-sqlstmt'] = $SQLStmt;
    $_SESSION['error-sqlprms'] = $SQLPrms;
    header("Location: "."error.php");
    exit();
}
$ROW_Result01 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RS_Result01);

EDIT: Adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the initiating call like this:
$SQLStmt = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_JSON_QueryPricingForOrder_v5.0] (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) OPTION (RECOMPILE);";
has resulted in a sub second response time from the function in the development environment.
This is the first time I have ever used OPTION (RECOMPILE) and I am aware that it is not an ideal 'fix' for this issue. Is there a better way to ensure on-going good practice?
The function definition is as follows:
USE [upgradeverify]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[udf_JSON_QueryPricingForOrder_v5.0]    Script Date: 07/07/2024 14:22:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION 
    [dbo].[udf_JSON_QueryPricingForOrder_v5.0]
    (
        @SiteId INT,
        @ContractorId INT = NULL,
        @ContainerId INT = NULL,
        @WasteTypeId INT = NULL,
        @ContainerSizeId INT = NULL,
        @ProductCategoryId INT = NULL,
        @ProductTypeId INT = NULL,
        @ProductId INT = NULL,
        @ServiceId INT = NULL,
        @WasteSubTypeId VARCHAR(300) = NULL,
        @WasteSubTypeQty VARCHAR(300) = NULL
    )

RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
-- Create CTE of child Client records

    WITH 
        /************************************************************************************************************************/
        /****** Create ClientList - list of all parent to this site                                                        ******/
        /************************************************************************************************************************/
        ClientList AS
            (
                SELECT
                    ClientHierarchy.ParentClientId,
                    ClientHierarchy.ChildClientId,
                    ClientHierarchy.Level,
                    Client.*
                FROM
                    ClientHierarchy
                INNER JOIN 
                    Client ON Client.ClientId = ClientHierarchy.ChildclientId
                WHERE
                    (
                        (ChildClientId = (SELECT ClientId FROM Site WHERE Site.SiteId = @SiteId)) -- define the starting point
                    )
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    ClientHierarchy.ParentClientId,
                    ClientHierarchy.ChildClientId,
                    ClientHierarchy.Level,
                    Client.*
                FROM
                    ClientHierarchy
                INNER JOIN 
                    Client ON Client.ClientId = ClientHierarchy.ChildclientId
                INNER JOIN
                    ClientList ON ClientHierarchy.ChildClientId = ClientList.ParentclientId
            ),

        /************************************************************************************************************************/
        /****** Create Markup - Retrieval of markup feilds from BaselinePriceMarkup                                        ******/
        /************************************************************************************************************************/

        Markup AS
            (
                SELECT
                    SalePriceMarkup,
                    RetailPriceMarkup
                FROM
                    BaselinePriceMarkup
            ),

        /************************************************************************************************************************/
        /****** Split the data input strings into CTE                                                                      ******/
        /************************************************************************************************************************/

        SplitWasteSubTypeId AS
            (
                SELECT 
                    value AS WasteSubTypeId,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row_num
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@WasteSubTypeId, ',')
            ),

        SplitWasteSubTypeQty AS
            (
                SELECT 
                    value AS WasteSubTypeQty,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row_num
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@WasteSubTypeQty, ',')
            ),

        /************************************************************************************************************************/
        /****** Cretae the Breakdown CTE from the split CTEs                                                               ******/
        /************************************************************************************************************************/

        Breakdown AS
            (
                SELECT 
                    s1.WasteSubTypeId,
                    s2.WasteSubTypeQty
                FROM SplitWasteSubTypeId s1
                LEFT OUTER JOIN SplitWasteSubTypeQty s2
                ON s1.row_num = s2.row_num
            ),

        /************************************************************************************************************************/
        /****** Create PriceList - Retrieval of raw data from ContractorPricing and BaselinePricing                        ******/
        /****** This will only Retrieve baseline prices for any client With Reseller = 1 Of Reseller is 0 then             ******/
        /****** ContractorPrice is returned                                                                                ******/
        /************************************************************************************************************************/

        Pricelist AS
            (
                SELECT
                CASE 
                    WHEN
                        ContainerID IS NOT NULL
                    THEN
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractorId,ContainerId,ContainerSizeId,WasteTypeId ORDER BY ContractorId,ContainerId,ContainerSizeId,WasteTypeId,Level DESC)
                    WHEN
                        ProductCategoryId IS NOT NULL
                    THEN
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractorId,ProductCategoryId,ProductTypeId,ProductId ORDER BY ContractorId,ProductCategoryId,ProductTypeId,ProductId,Level DESC)
                    WHEN
                        ServiceId IS NOT NULL
                    THEN
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractorId,ServiceId,WasteTypeId,WasteSubTypeId ORDER BY ContractorId,ServiceId,WasteTypeId,WasteSubTypeId,Level DESC)
                END AS RowNumber,
                *
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            ContractorPrice.ClientId,
                            ContractorPrice.SiteId,
                            CASE
                                WHEN ClientList.Level IS NULL
                            THEN 
                                40
                            ELSE
                                ClientList.Level
                            END AS Level,
                            0 AS BaselinePrice,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT BrokerPricing FROM ClientList WHERE BrokerPricing = 1)
                            THEN 
                                1
                            ELSE
                                0
                            END AS Reseller,
                            ContractorPrice.Reference,
                            ContractorPrice.ContractNotes,
                            ContractorPrice.ContractorId,
                            Contractor.ContractorName,
                            Contractor.Reference AS ContractorReference,
                            Contractor.AddrLine1 + ', ' + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine2 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine2 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine2 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine3 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine3 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine3 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine4 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine4 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine4 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            Contractor.AddrCity + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrCounty + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrPostcode AS ContractorAddress, 
                            Contractor.ContractorName + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrLine1 + ', ' + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine2 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine2 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine2 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine3 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine3 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine3 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine4 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine4 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine4 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            Contractor.AddrCity + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrCounty + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrPostcode AS ContractorFullAddress, 
                            ContractorPrice.ContainerId,
                            ContractorPrice.WasteTypeId,
                            ContractorPrice.ContainerSizeId,
                            ContractorPrice.ProductCategoryId,
                            ContractorPrice.ProductTypeId,
                            ContractorPrice.ProductId,
                            ContractorPrice.ServiceId,
                            ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
                            THEN 
                                CAST(CostHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId)
                            ELSE
                                CAST(CostHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2))
                            END AS CostHaulage,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
                            THEN 
                                CAST(CostTonnage AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId)
                            ELSE
                                CAST(CostTonnage AS NUMERIC(8,2))
                            END AS CostTonnage,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
                            THEN 
                                CAST(SaleHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId)
                            ELSE
                                CAST(SaleHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2))
                            END AS SaleHaulage,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
                            THEN 
                                CAST(SaleTonnage AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId)
                            ELSE
                                CAST(SaleTonnage AS NUMERIC(8,2))
                            END AS SaleTonnage,
                            IncludedTonnage
                        FROM
                            ContractorPrice
                        INNER JOIN  
                            Contractor ON Contractor.ContractorId = ContractorPrice.ContractorId
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            ClientList ON ClientList.ClientId = ContractorPrice.ClientId
                        WHERE
                            (
                                (
                                    (ContractorPrice.SiteId = @SiteId) OR
                                    (ContractorPrice.ClientId IN (SELECT ClientId FROM ClientList))
                                ) AND
                                (
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.ContractorId = @ContractorId) AND
                                        (@ContractorId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) OR
                                    (@ContractorId IS NULL)
                                ) AND
                                (Contractor.Active = 1) AND
                                (
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.ContainerId = @ContainerId) AND
                                        (@ContainerId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.WasteTypeId = @WasteTypeId) AND
                                        (@WasteTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.ContainerSizeId = @ContainerSizeId) AND
                                        (@ContainerSizeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) 
                                ) OR
                                (
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.ProductCategoryId = @ProductCategoryId) AND
                                        (@ProductCategoryId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.ProductTypeId = @ProductTypeId) AND
                                        (@ProductTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.ProductId = @ProductId) AND
                                        (@ProductId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) 
                                ) OR
                                (
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.ServiceId = @ServiceId) AND
                                        (@ServiceId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.WasteTypeId = @WasteTypeId) AND
                                        (@WasteTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId IN (SELECT WasteSubTypeId FROM Breakdown)) AND
                                        (@WasteSubTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) 
                                ) OR
                                (
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.ServiceId = @ServiceId) AND
                                        (@ServiceId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.WasteTypeId = @WasteTypeId) AND
                                        (@WasteTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (ContractorPrice.WasteSubTypeId IS NULL)
                                    ) 
                                )
                            )
                        UNION

                        SELECT
                            NULL AS ClientId,
                            SiteId,
                            50 AS Level,
                            1 As BaselinePrice,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT BrokerPricing FROM ClientList WHERE BrokerPricing = 1)
                            THEN 
                                1
                            ELSE
                                0
                            END AS Reseller,
                            BaseLinePriceHeader.Reference AS Reference,
                            'Baseline Price agreed with contractor' AS ContractNotes,
                            BaseLinePriceHeader.ContractorId,
                            Contractor.ContractorName,
                            Contractor.Reference AS ContractorReference,
                            Contractor.AddrLine1 + ', ' + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine2 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine2 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine2 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine3 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine3 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine3 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine4 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine4 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine4 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            Contractor.AddrCity + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrCounty + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrPostcode AS ContractorAddress, 
                            Contractor.ContractorName + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrLine1 + ', ' + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine2 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine2 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine2 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine3 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine3 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine3 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ((Contractor.AddrLine4 IS NOT NULL) AND (Contractor.AddrLine4 <> '')) THEN Contractor.AddrLine4 + ', ' ELSE '' END + 
                            Contractor.AddrCity + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrCounty + ', ' + 
                            Contractor.AddrPostcode AS ContractorFullAddress, 
                            BaseLinePriceDetail.ContainerId,
                            BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteTypeId,
                            BaseLinePriceDetail.ContainerSizeId,
                            BaseLinePriceDetail.ProductCategoryId,
                            BaseLinePriceDetail.ProductTypeId,
                            BaseLinePriceDetail.ProductId,
                            BaseLinePriceDetail.ServiceId,
                            BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
                            THEN 
                                CAST(CostHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId)
                            ELSE
                                CAST(CostHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2))
                            END AS CostHaulage,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
                            THEN 
                                CAST(CostTonnage AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId)
                            ELSE
                                CAST(CostTonnage AS NUMERIC(8,2))
                            END AS CostTonnage,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
                            THEN 
                                CAST(CEILING(BaselinePriceDetail.CostHaulage + ((BaselinePriceDetail.CostHaulage / 100) * (SELECT SalePriceMarkup FROM Markup))) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId)
                            ELSE
                                CAST(CEILING(BaselinePriceDetail.CostHaulage + ((BaselinePriceDetail.CostHaulage / 100) * (SELECT SalePriceMarkup FROM Markup))) AS NUMERIC(8,2))
                            END AS SaleHaulage,
                            CASE
                                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
                            THEN 
                                CAST(CEILING(BaselinePriceDetail.CostTonnage + ((BaselinePriceDetail.CostTonnage / 100) * (SELECT SalePriceMarkup FROM Markup))) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId)
                            ELSE
                                CAST(CEILING(BaselinePriceDetail.CostTonnage + ((BaselinePriceDetail.CostTonnage / 100) * (SELECT SalePriceMarkup FROM Markup))) AS NUMERIC(8,2))
                            END AS SaleTonnage,
                            IncludedTonnage
                        FROM
                            Site
                        INNER JOIN
                            [Postcodetools].[dbo].[PostcodeData] PCD ON REPLACE(PCD.PostCode,' ','') = REPLACE(Site.AddrPostcode,' ','')
                        INNER JOIN
                            BaseLinePriceSector ON BaseLinePriceSector.Sector = PCD.Sector
                        INNER JOIN
                            BaseLinePriceHeader ON BaseLinePriceHeader.BaseLinePriceHeaderId = BaseLinePriceSector.BaseLinePriceHeaderId 
                        INNER JOIN
                            BaseLinePriceDetail ON BaseLinePriceDetail.BaseLinePriceHeaderId = BaseLinePriceHeader.BaseLinePriceHeaderId
                        INNER JOIN  
                            Contractor ON Contractor.ContractorId = BaseLinePriceHeader.ContractorId
                        WHERE
                            (
                                (Site.SiteId = @SiteId) AND
                                (
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceHeader.ContractorId = @ContractorId) AND
                                        (@ContractorId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) OR
                                    (@ContractorId IS NULL)
                                ) AND
                                (Contractor.Active = 1) AND
                                (
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.ContainerId = @ContainerId) AND
                                        (@ContainerId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteTypeId = @WasteTypeId) AND
                                        (@WasteTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.ContainerSizeId = @ContainerSizeId) AND
                                        (@ContainerSizeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) 
                                ) OR
                                (
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.ProductCategoryId = @ProductCategoryId) AND
                                        (@ProductCategoryId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.ProductTypeId = @ProductTypeId) AND
                                        (@ProductTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.ProductId = @ProductId) AND
                                        (@ProductId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) 
                                ) OR
                                (
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.ServiceId = @ServiceId) AND
                                        (@ServiceId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteTypeId = @WasteTypeId) AND
                                        (@WasteTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId IN (SELECT WasteSubTypeId FROM Breakdown)) AND
                                        (@WasteSubTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) 
                                ) OR
                                (
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.ServiceId = @ServiceId) AND
                                        (@ServiceId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteTypeId = @WasteTypeId) AND
                                        (@WasteTypeId IS NOT NULL)
                                    ) AND
                                    (
                                        (BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId IS NULL)
                                    ) 
                                )
                            )
                    ) a
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (a.BaselinePrice = a.Reseller)
                        )
            )

        /************************************************************************************************************************/
        /****** Select results  based on the MAx Level for that particular service (Waste or Product)                      ******/
        /************************************************************************************************************************/

        SELECT
            (
                SELECT
                    leveldescription,
                    contractorid,
                    contractorname,
                    contractorreference,
                    contractoraddress,
                    contractorfulladdress,
                    SUM(CostHaulage) AS costhaulage,
                    SUM(CostTonnage) AS costtonnage,
                    SUM(SaleHaulage) AS salehaulage,
                    SUM(SaleTonnage) AS saletonnage,
                    includedtonnage
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            CASE
                                WHEN
                                    (
                                        SELECT
                                            COUNT(RowNumber)
                                        FROM
                                            PriceList
                                        WHERE
                                            RowNumber = 1
                                    ) > 1
                                THEN 
                                    CASE Pricelist.Level 
                                        WHEN 50 Then 'Baseline'
                                    ELSE
                                        'Contractor Price'
                                    END
                                ELSE
                                    CASE Pricelist.Level 
                                        WHEN 10 Then 'Head'
                                        WHEN 20 Then 'Area'
                                        WHEN 30 Then 'Branch'
                                        WHEN 40 Then 'Site'
                                    ELSE
                                        'Baseline'
                                    END
                            END AS leveldescription,
                            Pricelist.ContractorId AS contractorid,
                            Pricelist.ContractorName AS contractorname,
                            Pricelist.ContractorReference AS contractorreference,
                            Pricelist.ContractorAddress AS contractoraddress,
                            Pricelist.ContractorFullAddress AS contractorfulladdress,
                            Pricelist.Reference AS reference,
                            Pricelist.CostHaulage AS costhaulage,
                            Pricelist.CostTonnage AS costtonnage,
                            Pricelist.SaleHaulage AS salehaulage,
                            Pricelist.SaleTonnage AS saletonnage,
                            Pricelist.IncludedTonnage AS includedtonnage
                        FROM
                            Pricelist
                        WHERE
                            RowNumber = 1
                    ) a
                    GROUP BY
                        leveldescription,
                        contractorid,
                        contractorname,
                        contractorreference,
                        contractoraddress,
                        contractorfulladdress,
                        includedtonnage
                    ORDER
                        BY SaleHaulage
                    FOR JSON PATH
            ) AS JSONData
)



One interesting thing to note from the query is that when run on SSMS
the Query Text looks like this
(@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 varchar(8000),@4 varchar(8000))select * from [dbo] . [udf_JSON_QueryPricingForOrder_v5.0] ( @0 , null , null , @1 , null , null , null , null , @2 , @3 , @4 )
but when run from PHP it is using huge VARCHAR fields for all parameters:
(@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 varchar(max),@P3 varchar(max),@P4 nvarchar(4000),@P5 varchar(max),@P6 varchar(max),@P7 varchar(max),@P8 varchar(max),@P9 nvarchar(4000),@P10 nvarchar(4000),@P11 nvarchar(4000))SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_JSON_QueryPricingForOrder_v5.0] (@P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5,@P6,@P7,@P8,@P9,@P10,@P11)

SSMS sometimes "cheat" when loading a lot of data and truncates it. Can it be that this FOR JSON PATH output contains a lot of characters?

It's a pretty short JSON string at 633 chars.

is the function call query parametrized in php? or how does the call look?

I have edited the question to show the PHP code. It is a fully parameterised query.
I did some testing on the function and removing the JSON output had no effect on the response time. It obviously caused the application some issues because there was no JSON output but the Network time was the same.

I firmly believe that this is an issue on the SQL server side of things.

Then trace the call that PHP is making and replay it to reproduce the issue in SSMS.  Also capture the session wait stats for the PHP session. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16, and turn on the Query Store https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16

Yeah, that looks parametrized, is the function an inline table function? Perhaps try to run it parametrized in ssms and see how that goes. Or add OPTION(RECOMPILE)

I added OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the statement and.... behold we have a sub-second response from the Function call.
This is the first time I have ever used OPTION (RECOMPILE) and I am aware that it is not an ideal 'fix' for this issue. is there a better way to ensure on-going good practice?

Please show the function definition, and please share the query plans (slow and fast) via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

I have posted the function definition but the excecution plan is over 2MB and pastetheplan spits the dummy.

the function is inlined, but your php param types don't match, so it might help to have correctly matched parameters, although i'm not sure how that is achievable through php, but probably you should bin the array and use some other way of defining parameters, using binding or whatever it's called in php. Alternatively perhaps explicit CAST(? as INT) helps, but not sure

@siggemannen Non matching arguments shouldn't matter here much because they will be converted to the parameter types.

The porblem here is that your function has completely variegated access patterns, because many of your parameters are optional.
I can't give you a proper rewrite of your function, because it's pretty long, I don't have your schema and I don't know what results you are intending. But some points come to mind:

Consider writing separate functions for uses of ContainerID ProductCategoryId and ServiceId as these essentially make three different functions with different joins and conditions.
The best option is probably dynamic SQL instead of the function, as that means you can conditionally add joins and predicates as needed, and the compiler will work out the best plan for that. Don't forget to still parameterize, it's only the actual code you want to dynamically build, not the parameter values.
OPTION (RECOMPILE) is not a bad workaround if you can't rewrite it, given such a varied Kitchen Sink query.
Make sure PHP is passing the correct parameter types.
In the recursive CTE, remove the inner-join on Client and push it to the outside of the CTE.
Consider grouping up the results of that rCTE so that the compiler knows they are unique.
Change the UNION to UNION ALL if it makes sense to do so, as it's more efficient.
Use CONCAT_WS instead of messing around with ISNULL and conditional concat.
Instead of expressions such as
CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId AND WasteSubTypeQty IS NOT NULL)
  THEN 
      CAST(CostHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * (SELECT WasteSubTypeQty FROM Breakdown WHERE WasteSubTypeId = BaseLinePriceDetail.WasteSubTypeId)
  ELSE
      CAST(CostHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2))
  END

try left-joining Breakdown, then doing
  CAST(CostHaulage AS NUMERIC(8,2)) * ISNULL(b.WasteSubTypeQty, 1)


Instead of expressions such as
CASE
  WHEN
    (
      SELECT
          COUNT(RowNumber)
      FROM
          PriceList
      WHERE
          RowNumber = 1
    )

try using window functions. First get a DENSE_RANK inside PriceList
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractorId, ContainerId, ContainerSizeId, WasteTypeId ORDER BY Level DESC)

then use MAX to get the total number of distinct partitions (equivalent to COUNT(DISTINCT
CASE WHEN MAX(PriceList.dr) > 1

Or, if you are grouping it up anyway, just use normal aggregation functions without a subquery.
Note that using the same columns in the PARTITION BY and the ORDER BY is redundant, and the compiler will remove them.


It's a horrific function and is a real 'kitchen sink' job and I certainly appreciate the pointers. I will approach the client and see if we can get this re-written to mitigate some of the clunkiness. It looks like the function was expanded over time with conditional parameters until it became the mess that it is now.
Further investigation has revealed that, until recently, it was running OK but the introduction of the array has sent it over the edge performance wise.
